# WebRequest API does not log blocked mixed-content requests

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

This is with Chrome 70 and Firefox 63.

I am building a web extension that uses the webRequest API to check - among other things - for mixed-content requests and signal them to the user.

This is working fine on Firefox but it seems mixed-content requests that are blocked by Chrome (ie active mixed-content like script) do not appear at all when listening to webRequest events.

ie: such code:

```html
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
      (details) => {
          console.log('ON COMPLETED')
          console.log(details)
      },
      {
          urls: ['*://*/*'],
          types: ['font', 'image', 'media', 'script', 'stylesheet', 'sub_frame', 'xmlhttprequest']
      }
    )
```

does not list any blocked mixed-content request in Chrome while it does in Firefox. Note that these requests are listed in the chrome dev tools.

Similar code for other events have the same behavior. I tested **onBeforeRequest** and **onBeforeSendHeaders**

The only events that "works" is **onErrorOccurred**:

```html
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
      (details) => {
          console.log('ON ERROR OCCURED')
          console.log(details)
      },
      {
          urls: ['*://*/*'],
          types: ['font', 'image', 'media', 'script', 'stylesheet', 'sub_frame', 'xmlhttprequest']
      }
    )
```

This code will list the blocked requests but unfortunately without enough information to be useful. In the case of a request to an http resource blocked and showing as blocked in the chrome dev tools, the *details* provided by onErrorOccured are:

```
error: "net::ERR_ABORTED"
frameId: 0
fromCache: false
initiator: "https://www.zdnet.fr"
method: "GET"
parentFrameId: -1
requestId: "1227"
tabId: 18
timeStamp: 1544624802114.908
type: "script"
url: "https://www.zdnet.fr/actualites/https//js.sddan.com/GS.d?pa=22360&si=1&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zdnet.fr%2Factualites%2Fdes-sites-malveillants-profitent-d-un-bug-de-firefox-vieux-de-11-ans-39877807.htm&r=&rand=1544624801997"
```

2 problems here:

1 - the error (net::ERR_ABORTED) seems generic as it is also showing for a couple more requests that are NOT showing in the chrome dev tools. It's also reported in the case of 404s for instance.

2 - More importantly, the "url" property shows an https:// target. Meaning that I am not able to detect that this was a mixed-content request and report it to user.

Can anyone shed some light here? how can I get access to blocked mixed-content requests in chrome in a reliable manner?

Many thanks

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like an implementation quirk/feature of Chrome. Try posting on https://crbug.com if there was no such report.

Comment: Thanks I just did

Comment: @Weeblr Can you add an answer with a link to the bug you created?